# Android - Spinner view goes out of scrollview dimensions

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-scrollview

I have a *DialogActivity* name Measurement. It contains a Framelayout that is used to replace by "Fragment Top" Or "Fragment Bottom". Both these fragments (top/bottom) have a scrollview having a linear layout inside it and can have infinite sub fragments(Each row having 2 spinners and 1 editText) that are added using add button.

The problem is that when rows are added, the spinner arrows are displayed outside the dimensions of FrameLayout in this DialogActivity. EditText is hidden as it should be, the data of spinner is also hidden but the arrows are displayed as shown in the image below:

[image]

Here the center big box represents the frame layout area outside which the spinner must not be shown. I have also . highlighted top and bottom spinners that are shown outside the frame layout. Here is the code :

ActivityMeasurement

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.MeasurementActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/measurement_textView16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:text="Measurement"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/measurement_top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="196dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="top_btn"
        android:text="Top"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/measurement_textView16"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/measurement_bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="204dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="btm_btn"
        android:text="Bottom"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/measurement_textView16" 
    />


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/measurement_frame"
        android:layout_width="559dp"
        android:layout_height="476dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/measurement_textView16"> 
    </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**FragmentTop**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.topFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_top_ll1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="83dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_top_imageView4"
            android:layout_width="154dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="add"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_top_imageView3"
            android:layout_width="154dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="remove"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_minus" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**FragmentTopRow**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.topFragment_row">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="7">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/topFragment_row_sp1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"></Spinner>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/topFragment_row_sp2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"></Spinner>

        <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textAlignment="center"

        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this solution from another post
([ScrollView and Spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45442578/scrollview-and-spinner))

```
android:background="#00FFFFFF"
```

Works for me

Answer (score 0):

FragmentTop :Linear layout has weightsum 4 and both image view have weight 1. Also you are not using weight for height/width.
Can you check after correcting that